Flutter stuck at white screen after closing the app
In my app everything works fine, i get no errors etc. Problem is when i close app and debug or run it again it stucks on white screen. If i hot restart it works fine too but when i close it from debugger or from emulator and then re-run or re-debug it is white screen. Also when i change anything in code like deleting or adding a print and then debug or run it works fine again. Also in white screen i can click buttons inputs etc. but nothing shows up. I tried different emulators but same, i did not try in real device.
Edit: I tried it with a brand new application, just created a new app and run it. It is the same, so that made me thought that problem is not in my code, is it related to emulator or Flutter engine? In new project only visible thing was Colorscheme, deeppurple color.

Try to follow commands like - 1) flutter clean, 2) clean gradle for android with going to your project's android folder in terminal and ./gradlew clean and 3) flutter run. If you have already follow above steps then create .apk file and install on emulator or real device.

I tried without testing on a real device, nothing worked, i will test it on real device.

The white screen issue on app restart likely stems from asynchronous initialization, state restoration problems, or UI blocking during build. Here’s a quick checklist:
Ensure Proper Initialization: Use WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() in main() before running your app.
Check Asynchronous Operations: Ensure async code is complete before UI builds.
Inspect UI Rendering: Use Flutter Inspector to check if widgets are being built but not rendered correctly.
State Management: Verify state is correctly handled and restored.
Physical Device Test: Run the app on a real device to rule out emulator-specific issues.
Rebuild the App: Run flutter clean and rebuild.


I have WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() in main as a first thing to do. I have no problem in widget inspector and i deleted every operation in my main and made my home page a simple page only with a text widget to try on but it is still the same. Cleaning and re-building also does not work. Only thing works is changing something in code and re-build. This is so strange...

Since when problem start appearing ?

I am not sure but i used a swagger package to generate api coes, maybe after that. But as I say I am not sure.
